# What is wrong with my AMPScript LookUp function?

Tags: salesforce, exacttarget, ampscript

Long time lurker, first time poster. I really appreciate any help!

I am trying to pull Subject Lines from a separate data extension than our sendable data extension. There are different subject lines stored here, and they vary by each record.

I'm using the LookUp() function, but for some reason it only works if I choose the data extension that I am supposed to be looking up for a send preview in Exacttarget.

So let's say my sendable data extension is called "SendableDE" (creative, right?) and the data extension that I am looking up is "DEWithSubjectLines". For example, I have

```
%%[SET @subjectLine =     Lookup("DEWithSubjectLines","SUBJ_LINE","SUB_KEY",_subscriberkey)]%% Returns:     %%=v(@subjectLine)=%%
```

So, if I choose "SendableDE" when I do a Send Preview in ET, the function returns nothing.

But, if I choose "DEWithSubjectLines" when I do a send preview, the dynamic subject line is returned as intended and changes as I click through the different records. But why would it only work with that data extension? That pretty much defeats the purpose of the LookUp function.

I must be missing something conceptually here. Any thoughts? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Welcome, Jake.  You'll get a lot more eyes on your SFMC questions over at [salesforce.stackexchange.com](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com), specifically with the [Marketing-Cloud](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marketing-cloud) and [AMPScript](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ampscript) tags.

The `_subscriberkey` [personalization string](https://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/documentation/exacttarget/content/personalization_strings/) isn't assigned until an email is sent to an address for the first time.  Perhaps you're previewing against an email address that has never been sent an email from the account?  Unless your business requirements dictate otherwise, it might be a good idea to use the `emailaddr` personalization string instead:

```
%%[

var @subjectLine
set @subjectLine = Lookup("DEWithSubjectLines","SUBJ_LINE","SUB_KEY",emailaddr)

]%%
<br>@subjectLine:%%=v(@subjectLine)=%%
```

Comment: Hey Adam. Thanks for your response. I did go ahead and post a question over on  the SFMC board. Also, just want to say I follow your blog and it's great! One of the few resources out there for Ampscript. Thanks!